# Error when using for loops to make multiple objects with different name in R

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I'm trying to make 6 different objects titled env1, env2, env3... and so on by labelling them and calling audio files with the corresponding names.

I just can't understand why this is keep throwing errors at me.

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  trial <- paste0("env", i)
  trial[i] <- slider_page(trial[i],
                          div(p(trial[i]),
                                tags$audio(src = paste0("audioResources/", trial[i], ".mp3"),
                                                type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = FALSE, control = FALSE)
                              ),
                          min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, tick = FALSE)
  print(trial[i])
}
```

The error says

> Error in trial[i] <- slider_page(trial[i], div(p(trial[i]), tags$audio(src = paste0("audioResources/",  :
> incompatible types (from S4 to character) in subassignment type fix

Can anybody help me explain why this isn't working?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe just a typo. Try with `tags$audio` instead of `tag$audio`.

Comment: I didn't see that! Thanks a lot. But now I'm getting a different error... "incompatible types (from S4 to character) in subassignment type fix", which I now edited into the original question.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the data and knowing what library those are coming from. There is something that doesn't make sense *to me*. Why are you defining trial as a single string in each iteration of a loop and then subsetting it?

Comment: @svenhalvorson Looking back at it after your comment, I realised the confusion over what you said is the problem. I'm basically trying to make multiple objects with different names but don't know the proper way to do so. An alternative I tried thinking of is `trial <- c("env1", "env2", "env3", "env4", "env5", "env6")
for (i in 1:6) { trial[i] <-...` but that doesn't seem to be right either...

Comment: I think I see the problem here. What you have is an atomic vector `trial` which can only have strings as its values. The return value from `slider_page` is not a string and thus cannot be set as one of the values of `trial`. Instead, store the results in a list: `output = vector('list', 6)`. Note that you have to change the assignment here to be like `output[[i]] = slider_pate(...)`.